# object doesn't support named arguments

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing VBA code to write data from SQL Server, there is no problem with connection., but when I debug the code in record set part system throws

*runtime error 446 object doesn't support named arguments*

Here is my code

```
`Sub CopyfromDatabase()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim RecordConn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set RecordConn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=PH03\Historian;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=OCG;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=HistorianStorage"
conn.Open
'On Error GoTo CloseConnection
With RecordConn
.ActiveConnection = conn
.Source = "connectiontable"
.LockType = adLockReadOnly
.CursorType = adforwardonly
.Open
End With
On Error GoTo CloseRecord
Worksheets.Add
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RecordConn
CloseRecord:
RecordConn.Close
'CloseConnection:
conn.Close
End Sub`
```

Help me!!

Comment: Try `Set .ActiveConnection = conn`

Comment: No, same error appears..

Comment: Exactly which line gives the error?

Comment: Nevermind - you have declared RecordConn as a `Connection` object, but I guess you meant it to be a `RecordSet` object ?

Comment: `ActiveConnection = conn` this line only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim RecordConn As ADODB.Connection
Set RecordConn = New ADODB.Connection
```

should be

```
Dim RecordConn As ADODB.Recordset
Set RecordConn = New ADODB.Recordset
```

Comment: Precise answer i was looking for